# Каким образом убрать границы элемента Scale

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui

[image: Шкала имеет белые границы по котуру]

Каким образом можно убрать белую границу у шкалы опция bd не решает вопроса.

```
Degree1 = Scale(main_window, orient=VERTICAL, length=300,from_=0,to=180,tickinterval=20, resolution=1, troughcolor='#414977', command=lambda value: send(1, value))
Degree1['bg']='#4c7c9a'
Degree1['foreground']='#3a3663'
```

Comment: параметр `highlightthickness`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Методом подбора (список параметров брал отсюда: [The Tkinter Scale Widget, config method](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scale.htm#Tkinter.Scale.config-method)) определил, что за ширину этой рамки отвечает параметр `highlightthickness`:

```
from tkinter import *

main_window = Tk()
main_window['bg'] = '#4c7c9a'
main_window.geometry("200x350")

Degree1 = Scale(main_window, orient=VERTICAL, length=300,from_=0,to=180,tickinterval=20, resolution=1, troughcolor='#414977')
Degree1['bg']='#4c7c9a'
Degree1['foreground']='#3a3663'

Degree1['highlightthickness']=0

Degree1.pack()

main_window.mainloop()
```

[image: Скриншот]